# pickle files load into Databricks

Tags: databricks, pickle, large-files

I am trying to load some large .pk files (2Gb) into Databricks to run experiments. I have these files loaded into my local drives (no cloud).
When I try to import them directly in the Repos I have the error message that file is too large. I tried to load the files in google cloud as well, but I have to be admin to establish connection between the platforms

How to load and access those files in Databricks?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload file to [DBFS](https://docs.databricks.com/dbfs/index.html) (Databricks File System).  For example, you can use [Databrick CLI's](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/dbfs-cli.html) `fs` command for that. Configure Databricks CLI as described in documentation, and then just do:

```
databricks fs cp local_file dbfs:/path_on_dbfs
```